# What does each line mean in squid3

Tags: squid

In Ubuntu, I have been watching a file, using the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/squid3/access.log
```

And I am getting the following info back, but what does it mean?

```
1447666725.917   6820 192.168.0.200 TCP_MISS/200 917 POST http://website1.website.com/ - HIER_DIRECT/192.100.1.4 text/plain
1447666730.825     22 192.168.0.200 TCP_MISS/200 1183 GET http://website2.website.com/fetch? - HIER_DIRECT/192.0.1.40 text/xml
```

What does the `6820` and the `22` mean?

I thought they would be ports, but then looking at other info above, it definitely doesn't look like ports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the second column represents the time in milliseconds the request took:

> The native format for Squid
>
> The format is:
>
> time elapsed remotehost code/status bytes method URL rfc931
>   peerstatus/peerhost type

See also http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LogFormat for more details about the logformat.

Comment: Thanks mate. So it then means: time=`1447666725.917` elapsed=`6820` remotehost=`192.168.0.250` and so on...